# ReactJS - nested route will not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

### Code Sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/patches-xy8h2l?file=/src/components/Support/Products/index.js

Recreate the problem by going to "Access Driver Systems Here" -> All Products -> SuperServerLine

The problem is that as the page is rerendered with different URLs fetchProducts should be rerun. Different parts of fetchProducts will run depending on what route parameters are provided (`productLine` and `server`). However, these are always undefined no matter what URL you access. Working means it should print three servers: "You did it 1", "Victory 2", and "It's Working 3"

You can fix the problem by changing the support component in the following way:

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Products from "./Products";
import Product from "./Product";
import Dashboard from "../Admin/Dashboard";
import XmlDetails from "./Products/XmlDetails";
import "./style.css";

function Support() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet>
        <title>Product Support | Dell US</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="products/:category?/*"
          element={
            <div className="support-products">
              <Products />
            </div>
          }
          exact
        />
        <Route path=":category/:device" element={<Product />} />
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="catalogs" element={<XmlDetails />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Support;
```

However, this then breaks other aspects of the routing. It's not clear to me why the parameters don't work as is.

### Parent Component (support/index.js)

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Products from "./Products";
import "./style.css";

function Support() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet>
        <title>Product Support</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="products/*"
          element={
            <div className="support-products">
              <Products />
            </div>
          }
          exact
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Support;
```

### Child Component (support/products/index.js)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  NavLink,
  Link,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useParams,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";
import http from "../../http";
import { strCompare } from "../../util";
import "./style.css";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";

function Products() {
  // Here, 'ProductLine' might be something like "SuperServerLine" or "server 2",
  // and 'server' could be something like "server 3".
  const { productLine, server } = useParams(); // <- Example values for productLine and server
  const location = useLocation();
  const [productLines, setProductLines] = useState([]);
  const [servers, setServers] = useState([]);
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(null);
  console.log("productLine:", productLine); // Debugging line
  console.log("server:", server); // Debugging line

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.state !== undefined && location.state !== null) {
      setAuthorized(location.state.authorized);
    }

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      if (!productLine) {
        try {
          const res = await http.get("/api/brands");
          if (res.brands.length === 0) {
            alert("No product lines available");
          } else {
            setProductLines(res.brands.sort());
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Failed to fetch product lines:", error);
        }
        // If there's a productLine (e.g., "SuperServerLine") but no specific server (e.g., "server 1"),
        // fetch the systems for that productLine.
      } else if (productLine && !server) {
        // The endpoint will include the productLine value (e.g., "/api/systems?brand=SuperServerLine").
        try {
          const res = await http.get("/api/systems?brand=" + productLine);
          if (res.systems.length === 0) {
            alert("No servers for this product available");
          } else {
            res.systems.sort((a, b) => strCompare(a.system_id, b.system_id));
            // setServers(res.systems); REMOVING FOR MOCK
            setServers(mockServers);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Failed to fetch servers:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchProducts();
  }, [productLine, server, location.state]);

  const getBreadCrumbs = () => {
    let path = location.pathname.split("/").filter(Boolean);
    let crumbs = [];
    crumbs.push({ label: "All " + path[0], path: `/${path[0]}/` });
    for (let i = 1; i < path.length; i++) {
      if (path[i]) {
        crumbs.push({
          label: path[i],
          path: `${crumbs[i - 1].path}${path[i]}/`
        });
      }
    }
    return crumbs;
  };

  return (
    <div className="products-content container">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-6">
            {authorized === false && (
              <div className="error-box">
                <Alert variant="danger">
                  Please contact administrator for access to admin page
                </Alert>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="product-nav">
        {getBreadCrumbs().map((crumb) => {
          return (
            <div key={crumb.label}>
              <NavLink to={crumb.path} className="breadcrumb-active" end>
                {crumb.label}
              </NavLink>
              <span className="breadcrumb-delim">/</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <ListProductLines productLines={["SuperServerLine"]} exact />
            }
          />
          <Route
            path=":productLine"
            element={<ListServers servers={servers} />}
          />
          <Route path=":productLine/:server*" element={<div>We made it</div>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Component to render a list of product lines SuperServerLine, etc
function ListProductLines({ productLines }) {
  return (
    <div className="product-links row">
      {/* Map over the 'productLines' array and render each product */}
      {productLines.map((prod, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="component-link col-xs-12 col-md-3">
          {/* Create a link to the product page using 'renderProductName' to form the URL */}
          <Link to={`/products/${prod}`}>
            {/* Display the product name using 'renderProductName' */}
            {prod}
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// Function to render a list of products for a specific productLine, e.g., servers R440, R7625, etc.
function ListServers({ servers }) {
  return (
    <div className="product-links row">
      {servers.map((prod, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i} className="component-link col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <Link to={`./${prod.system_id}/drivers`}>
              {`${prod.brand} ${prod.name}`}
            </Link>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const mockServers = [
  {
    system_id: "05CE",
    system_id_type: "MULTISYSTEMCHASSIS",
    brand: "SuperServerLine",
    name: "Server 1",
    created_at: "2023-08-16T17:59:22.249Z",
    updated_at: "2023-08-16T17:59:22.249Z"
  },
  {
    system_id: "05CF",
    system_id_type: "MULTISYSTEMCHASSIS",
    brand: "SuperServerLine",
    name: "Server 2",
    created_at: "2023-08-16T17:59:22.249Z",
    updated_at: "2023-08-16T17:59:22.249Z"
  },
  {
    system_id: "05D0",
    system_id_type: "MULTISYSTEMCHASSIS",
    brand: "SuperServerLine",
    name: "Server 3",
    created_at: "2023-08-16T17:59:22.249Z",
    updated_at: "2023-08-16T17:59:22.249Z"
  }
];

export default Products;
```

Comment: Is the issue that `category` is an optional path segment? Both `path="products/:category?/*"` and `path="products/*"` are *correct* for the `Support` component, so it seems the descendent routes need to have their routes adjusted accordingly. The issue, it seems, is between the `ProductLine` that you want to render on `"/products/:category"` (*or `"/products"`*) and the `ListServers` that you want to render on `"/products/:category/:productLine"` (*or `"/products/:productLine"`*). So the question to you is basically: "What exactly do you want your routes to be?"

Comment: It should render a list of product lines on `/products/:productLine` and then the user should be able to click productLine and it lists out the servers in that product line. Finally, you can click each individual server and it displays info on that server (`/products/:productLine/:server`). Edit: The original author had `path="products/:category?/*"` in the parent and I updated it to `products/*` because it wasn't entirely clear to me why the parent would have `path="products/:category?/*"`

Comment: So, render `ProductLine` on `"/products/:productLine"` and `Product` on `"/products/:productLine/:server"`, .... so something like `ListServers` on `"/products/:productLine/servers"`?

Comment: ProductLine renders on `/products/` because it's a list of all the product lines. Then on `/products/:productLine/` you have a list of servers in that product line and then `/products/:productLine/:server` should get you the data for some individual server in the product line. I'm open to changing that schema - that's just how I had intended to set it up. Edit: I'm not sure why the original author made the root /products - I've already updated a lot of the naming... it was even more confusing originally 

Comment: But it seems `ProductLine` needs to be rendered on path `"/products/:productLine"` so `productLine` is a defined path parameter so it can make the data requests. The other components/routes need to be adjusted. The alternative is to push the `useEffect` hook's data fetching logic down the ReactTree to the other descendent routes so `ProductLine` doesn't need `productLine` for anything.

Comment: Incorrect - that part of the logic works. I should rename the function ProductLine ProductLines. Hold on, I'm going to update it to clear up the ambiguity. That function is responsible for listing *all* of the product lines. Not a single product line. If I stick with `/products/*` in the parent - really where I'm stuck is why `const { productLine, server } = useParams();` stops working in the child. Even when the url is `https://10.10.25.130/products/someProductLine/someTestServer`, the router params productLine and server are undefined on all renders

Comment: It might depend on what version of `react-router-dom` you are using. Think you could create a pared-down, ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code (*with mocked data calls preferably*)?

Comment: Probably - I've never used it before. Probably will take 20 minutes or so

Comment: /Edit - didn't want to make it odd. Didn't think of this but I can't do it beacuse it requires the backend as well

Comment: Can you just mock the API requests, e.g. just update the state to a small example data subset (*like 5-10 example entries*)? We don't technically need to reproduce the data fetching, just the rendering of the data.

Comment: Done - I have recreated the behavior and posted the link in the OP. That's a handy trick, thanks for suggesting it. I'll have to use that more often

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254972/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-grant-curell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Routes` component doesn't appear to be capable of reading any of the dynamic route path segments of any descendent `Routes` components (*e.g. routed components rendering another set of `Routes` and `Route` components*). `Routes` can read the path params of *any* of the routes it is *directly* rendering, and any routes with trailing `"*"` (*splat*) wildcard matchers will simply place the "rest of the path" on a splat parameter.

For example, if a route's path is `"/:test/*"` and the current URL path is `"/segment1/segment2/segment3"`, then the following is what is accessible:

```js
const { test, "*": splat } = useParams();
console.log(test);  // "segment1"
constol.log(splat); // "segment2/segment3"
```

`Products` is rendered on `"/products/*"`, so this means that any more deeply nested routes will be on the splat. You could do a little bit of trivial string splitting and array destructuring assignment to get the `productLine` and `server` path segment values.

Update `Product` from

```js
const { productLine, server } = useParams();
```

to

```js
const { "*": splat } = useParams();
const [productLine, server] = splat.split("/");
```

[image: Edit reactjs-nested-route-will-not-render]